# Feature Importance from GridSearchCV

Tags: python, feature-selection, random-forest, python-3.x, gridsearchcv

I created a GridSearchCV for a Random Forest Regressor. Now I want to check the feature importance. I searched around and I found this:

```
rf_gridsearch.best_estimator_.named_steps.feature_importances_
```

This already works, but my training data is huge, 669 attributes. Therefore, I need the attribute names. So I found this code:

```
rf_gridsearch.best_estimator_.named_steps["step_name"].feature_importances_
```

But I don't know what the "named_steps["step_name"]" are.

I tried something like this:

```
named_steps = X_train.columns
```

But this doesn't work. Could somebody explain me what `named_steps["step_name"]` is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you just need:

```
feature_importances = rf_gridsearch.best_estimator_.feature_importances_
```

This provides the feature importance for all the attributes in your dataset. For more information on this as well as other options, you may also refer to the [Scikit-learn official documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html).

Comment: I already tried that and i get this

Comment: array([1.15007706e-02, 1.52749118e-02, 4.92813973e-03, 5.79714037e-03, .... for 669 Attributes. I want also the column name for the results

Comment: The order of this values are the same as the order in the dataset. So the column names are just the X.columns

Comment: So i just need to sort them to figure out what the most importante score is?

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Comment: @ml_learner I believe this answers your query. If so, please mark it as an Accepted Answer. That shall help others in future. :)

Answer (score 1):

This I how did to tie the feature importance values to column names

```
hd = list(XData.columns)
for i, f in zip(hd, best_result.best_estimator_.feature_importances_):
     print(i,round(f*100,2))
```